# What is division?

Tags: arithmetic

In mathematics we have the *Addition* operation from which subtraction and multiplication can be resulted. so it's not wrong to say they both have the concept of addition within them. $$ a*b = a+a+...+a \ \ \ \ \ (b\ times)$$
and $$ a-b = a+ (-b) .$$
division has the concept of multiplication within it: $$ \frac{a}{b} = a* \frac{1}{b}$$ 
but I'm not so sure if it is so, because there is still division in it in $ \frac{1}{b} $ and can't be decomposed any more as far as I know.

also, I assume division doesn't have the concept of addition in it: no way to say how $ \frac{a}{b} $ can be decomposed to addition, and also no way to say how it's possible to add "a", $ \frac{1}{b} $ times.

$ Q_1 $: so how is *Division* related to or can be derived from Addition and Multiplication?

$Q_2$ : what branch of math is this subject related to?

Comment: In abstract algebra, there is a structure called a [division ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring) that generalizes division from fields like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ to a broader class of rings.

Comment: Yes; *inverse* operation. $a - a=0$ as well as $a \times \dfrac 1 a =1$.

Comment: Algebra? In a group $(G,\cdot)$, each element is invertible, i.e. there exists a neutral (identity) element $e\in G$ such that for every $g\in G$, there exists a unique $g'\in G$ such that $g\cdot g' = g'\cdot g = e$. Here, you want real numbers $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\times)$ is a group, and the identity element is $1$..

Comment: And the subject is [arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Arithmetic_operations).

Comment: 1/b is the inverse of b, it is usually stated as an axiom in say analysis, where every element of a field, say, has a multiplicative inverse. I would also say fields is a part of abstract algebra, which goes much further in depth than analysis.

Comment: On Q1 concerning the link with addition: $\frac{a}{n}+\cdot+\frac{a}{n}=a$ (sum of $n$ terms on LHS).

Comment: You say that $\frac{a}{b}=a*\frac{1}{b}$ still has division in it, the exact same applies to $a-b = a + (-b)$, It's just that in this second notation we don't write the neutral element $0$ anymore, but you can: $a-b = a + (0-b)$. Both cases are examples of the exact same thing (note that in the first case, the $1$ is also the neutral element). yet in the case of substraction you are sure but in the case of division you are not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Division, as an operation, is the inverse of multiplication. So, the number $$\frac ab$$ is **defined** to be the ***unique*** solution to the equation $$b\cdot x = a.$$

This definition also explains why

- $\frac a0$ is not defined for $a\neq 0$ (because there is **no** solution to the equation $0x=a$ in that case)
- $\frac 00$ is not defined (because there is more than one solution to the equation $0\cdot x = 0$.

Comment: thank you, so there is no division it's basically multiplication for numbers greater than 0 and less than 1. is that it?

Comment: if that's true, how can you explain 0.5 * b? add b half times?

Comment: @parvin Well sure there **is** such a thing as division. It's just that yes, division is the same thing as multiplication by the inverse. And the same thing as solving an equation.

Comment: @parvin $0.5 b$ is the number that solves the equation $2x=b$.

Comment: so it's just a mathematical concept, as you said. I was trying to explain it with the real world examples.

Comment: That first analogy was not quite right. If you think about $\frac{14}{7}$, you'll come unstuck. Think of division as doing multiplication backwards - we call that the inverse. If you want to change the term "divide by $x$" to "multiply by the inverse of $x$", that's your prerogative :-).

Comment: @MattS Which not-quite-right analogy are you talking about?

Comment: @parvin You can have a real world example. I you have $b$ litres of milk, then $0.5\cdot b$ litres of milk is the amount of milk you must give each person if you want to split all the milk equally among $2$ people.

Comment: @Arthur I was talking about the "there is no division it's basically multiplication for numbers greater than 0 and less then 1." analogy.